# C# UTF-8 from bytes confusion

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding

Why does

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte [] { (byte)0xa0 });
```

not result in

```
"\u00a0"
```

?

I'm getting back `"\ufffd"` instead.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space 0xa0 should be a valid non-breaking space in UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*0xa0 should be a valid non-breaking space in UTF-8.*

No, it is not. This is valid in both Latin1 and Unicode (or UTF-16 and UTF-32) character sets.

In UTF-8 encoding it's encoded as `C2 A0`. Generally, only characters lower than `0x80` are mapped to single byte in UTF-8.

Comment: ah, thanks.  so if i have 8 byte text with a 0xa0 byte that is supposed to be a space then is it most likely Latin1 encoding?

Comment: There are several encodings that map U+00A0 to 0xA0. Latin-1 (which in turn is ambiguous between the ISO and Windows encoding of that name) is a likely bet, but not certain.

Comment: @CoderBrien : Most probably. Or any other old fashioned one byte encodings.

Comment: excellent.  i've had a tough time groking encodings but this opened the door for me.  much appreciated!!!